# Does NOT support http GET when sending POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, iis, post

tried looking around the web a bit and am at a loss.
currently setting up a REST api.

locally using postman i send the **POST** to the end point and all is well.
once its pushed to the test server and i run the **POST**

```
Status: 405 Method Not Allowed

{
  "message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."
}
```

controller looks like and as said, I am able to post locally just not to test server

```
    [HttpPost, Route("")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(string))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateSomething([FromBody] obj stuff)
```

c# generated by post man

```
    var client = new RestClient("http://test-api.someurl.com/makestuff/makethisthing/");
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("postman-token", "not sure if this is needed but post man put it here");
    request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer [A Very long OAuth token]");
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

it works fine locally running on local iis (**not** iis express) on my pc and other dev pc. once put to test server then get that error message. i know i am using post as i am using postman with {{server}} env var and just changing from local to test env so the post itself is not chaining at all

there are currently a handful of other end points in separate web applications that are working fine.

any point in the right direction, thank you

Comment: Does it having the problem of Cross Origin Request (CORS) ? @workabyte

Comment: Review your controller method.  Is it marked with `[HttpGet]` ?

Comment: @AaronHudon, added my controller code. it works fine locally running on local iis on my pc and other dev pc. once put to test server then get that error message. i know i am using post as i am using postman with {{server}} env var and just changing from local to test env so the post itself is not chaining

Comment: @PassionInfinite, nope. just simple post "make something" from my pc to test server. test server puts in database. have many of these currently working but just this one with this odd error

Comment: i am feeling like this may be some config setting that i am missing but not seeing anything obvious in IIS

Comment: Are you _certain_ you are using a POST when testing this? The error message seems to imply you are sending a GET.

Comment: @petelids, i am positive i have POST selected as the verb on postman. am attaching the post man code export just to prove. but that is why i am so confused by this.

Comment: Any potential for a redirect? A redirect will actually return a 301 or 302 with a `Location` header. The client then requests that URL there via GET, even if the initial request was a POST.

Comment: @ChrisPratt updated question but i am getting 405 Method not allowed

Comment: Well, yeah. I get that. My question was is there a redirect involved, because the flow then would be something like: POST -> 302 -> GET -> 405.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, oh.... good point. let me check that

Comment: @ChrisPratt, you are absolutely correct. in my case it was a 302 cause by http in url instead of https. after your comment about the redirect i used chrome inspector and there it was. THANK YOU. please post as answer so i can accept for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're sure you're requesting via POST, but the error unambiguously says you're attempting a GET, the only thing that makes sense is that there's a redirect occurring. A redirect will actually return a 301 or 302 with a Location header. The client then requests that new URL there via GET, even if the original request was a POST. In other words, the flow would be something like: POST -> 302 -> GET -> 405.

Answer (score 0):

Name the action method with a specific route.  E.g. `/controller/create-something-post/`

```
[HttpPost, Route("create-something-post")]
[ResponseType(typeof(string))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateSomething([FromBody] obj stuff)
{
}
```

Comment: thank you but i have a separate GET method and i am NOT sending a get request i am sending a POST request so it should pick it up

Comment: thank you again but the route is intentionally "" and is the same on 5 other end points we have in separate web applications on same server that are currently working

Comment: im using PostMan and the verb selected is POST and it works locally then only changing the server address

Comment: the route is set to "" and the site is pushed to /makestuff
have like 5 others doing the same thing the same way and it also works locally. with the only change being localhost -> test-api.something.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128383/discussion-between-aaron-hudon-and-workabyte).